# How to insert an items into an array in specific location and more

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

My goal is to have an array (with 40 items for example) which in it :
1.The string '**blue**' will appear every 2 items till the end.
2.The string '**red**' will appear every 3 items till the end.
3.If the position of the '**blue**' and the '**red**' string are match,(like in [0]),the string in that position will be '**purple**'.
3.Every item which is not **blue red** or **purple** will contain the string 'empty'.

Think of it as as mixed colors, whenever blue and red are in the same position (starts with [0]) it should be purple.

it should be like this one:

```
var array = ['purple','empty','empty','blue','red','empty','blue','empty','red',....];
```

My attempt:

```js
Array.prototype.insert = function(index, item) {
  this.splice(i, 0, item);
};
var measure = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  measure.insert(0 + i * 2, 'blue')
  measure.insert(0 + i * 3, 'red')
}
console.log(measure);
```

Comment: I have tried a lot but deleting most of it lol...that is what is left:

Comment: Done it above :)

Comment: I clicked  `<>` and created a [mcve] for you

Comment: Where is the word "purple"?

Comment: the meaning is that whenever blue and red in the same position it will be purple, Ill fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize your array to length 40. Using a for loop till the length of the array, you can place your conditions and populate data accordingly.

```js
var arr = new Array(40);
for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0 && i % 3 === 0){
    arr[i] = 'purple';
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    arr[i] = 'red';
  } else if (i % 2 === 0) {
    arr[i] = 'blue';
  } else {
    arr[i] = 'empty';
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Amazing! ty very much :)